# When every matrix is a sum of nilpotent (idempotent or invertible) matrices ??

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with non-zero identity. Consider the following three properties:

1. Every $A \in M_n(R)$ is a sum of nilpotent matrices.
2. Every $A \in M_n(R)$ is a sum of idempotent matrices.
3. Every $A \in M_n(R)$ is a sum of invertible  matrices.

Is there any characterization for rings that have one of these properties ?? For example since the trace of a nilpotent matrix is zero (for matrices over a commutative ring with identity) then 1 can not hold fot every $A$ (at least in commutative case). But I don't know the status of other conditions over a general ring. I you know please let me know.

Comment: That the trace of a nilpotent matrix is always zero is not true (consider a $1\times1$ matrix).

Comment: #1 is false for $n=1$ for any commutative ring $R$. A sum of nilpotent elements in a commutative ring is nilpotent, so you won't be able to get any non-nilpotent elements (like the identity, for example.)

Comment: Off topic but might entertain you: a *clean ring* is one in which each element is a sum of a unit and an idempotent.